# Confused how to add this code before the closing tag of the functions.php file

Tags: php, function

My functions php file ends like this

```
//Setup custom settings when theme is activated

if (isset($_GET['activated']) && $_GET['activated']){

//Add default contact fields

$pp\_contact\_form = get\_option('pp\_contact\_form');

if(empty($pp\_contact\_form))

{

    add\_option( 'pp\_contact\_form', 's:1:"3";' );

}



$pp\_contact\_form\_sort\_data = get\_option('pp\_contact\_form\_sort\_data');

if(empty($pp\_contact\_form\_sort\_data))

{

    add\_option( 'pp\_contact\_form\_sort\_data', 'a:3:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";}' );

}


wp\_redirect(admin\_url("admin.php?page=functions.php&activate=true"));
}

?>
```

I need to add the following code before the closing tag of my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function ( $strings ) { /** * Holding translations/changes. * 'to translate' => 'the translation or rewording' */ $text = array( 'Any Brand' => 'Any Brands', 'Any Type'=>'Any Types', 'Search'=>'Searches' ); $strings = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $strings ); return $strings; }, 20 );
```

But where exactly?

Comment: This is not really clear what you're asking. You're answering your question yourself, *"I need to add the following code before the closing tag of my functions.php file"* *"But where exactly?"* <-- before the closing tag

Comment: This is the "closing tag": `?>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what/when you want add_filter to run. If it should run whenever you call your functions.php, add it before the ?> at the end (that marks the end of PHP code, the start usually looks like <?php). But if you only want it to run when $_GET['activated'] is set, you need it on a line above }.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, I'm not familiar with WordPress.